# Unix sorting command by second last letter

Tags: sorting, unix

I have a text file containing hexadecimal color codes but I want to be to sorted by their alpha value. How do I go about it using the -k sorting option. I basically want the codes with ff alpha values to be sorted first.

Color Codes:

```
#b293a6ff
#ead58fff
#a69d36ff
#067806ff
#7f0bf712
#f8b366ff
#8946d744
#c927d4ff
#3e568bff
#3e1ce1ff
#11570a00
```

Command:

```
sort -k8,9 colours.txt
```

Expected Output:

```
#b293a6ff
#ead58fff
#a69d36ff
#067806ff
#f8b366ff
#c927d4ff
#3e568bff
#3e1ce1ff
#11570a00
#7f0bf712
#8946d744
```

Comment: Could you please do add sample of expected output in your question and let us know then?

Comment: Added an expected output there

Comment: Do you really want to sort on the last 2 characters only, and have `ff < 00 < 12` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU `sort`:

Not exactly your expected output (see the last three entries), but sorted by the last two characters in reverse order 
using `--stable` to leave entries with the same values (`ff`) in their original order.

```
$ sort --stable -rk1.8 colours.txt
#b293a6ff
#ead58fff
#a69d36ff
#067806ff
#f8b366ff
#c927d4ff
#3e568bff
#3e1ce1ff
#8946d744
#7f0bf712
#11570a00
```